# Getting Details from one Dynamic Page to Another - Re-Post

Tags: php, jquery, json, variables, joomla2.5

After some wrestling with almost every line of code written for the JoomShopping component I beleive I have found what should be the answer to all my woes.

When activating the "Buy" button in the shopping list and once clicked on it uses the following link syntax in order to post a Product to the Checkout Cart:

```
index.php/cart/add?category_id=2&product_id=12&quantity=4
```

Where 2 is the Category ID and 12 is the Product ID etc ... This was solved by V.Vachev, but I thought it prudent to post all of the finished/fixed oced as it works:

```
    $('.checkOut').live('click',function(){
    var products= new Array();
$(".jshop_prod_cart").each(function(){
    var product = new Object();
        product.catid = $(this).find('[name="category_id"]').val();
            product.id = $(this).find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
            product.qanty = $(this).find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
    products.push(product) 
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                url: "shop-portal/add?category_id="+products[0].catid+"&product_id="+products[0].id+"&quantity="+products[0].qanty,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    })

        })
    })
```

this returns:

> http://www.domain.com/index.php/shop-portal/add?category_id=2&product_id=48&quantity=4

BUT it is only returning the 1 and I have multiple dynamic entries which all need to be captured as such.

I am researching this, it seems I need to cache this information somehow ... Any ideas?

Comment: Check my edit, I hope it will help:)

Comment: I have and I found that it is my spelling that is attrocious after 11 hours of solid coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL passing wasn't correct. It should be like that:

```
    url: "/shop-portal/add?category_id="+catid+"&product_id="+id+"&quantity="+qanty,
```

Now I see that you have array with the same names ("catid", "quantity" ...). Do you eventually want to send the values from the array? Because this is another thing. Make sure that "catid", "id" and "qanty" are global variables and you send the desired values.

Joomla is probably not expecting JSON data, try with native ajax request

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert("Sent!");
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/shop-portal/add?category_id="+yourvariable+"&product_id="+yourvariable+"&quantity="+yourvariable);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I'm not sure what values you want to send. Take care of them (yourvariable1, yourvariable2...)

Now I see that you want to pass values from the array. Try with

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data:products,
    url: "/shop-portal/add?category_id="+products[0].catid+"&product_id="+products[0].id+"&quantity="+products[0].qanty,
    dataType: 'json',
    })
})
```

This request will send only the values from the first product. Products is an array so you probably must loop thru it and send multiple requests in order to send everything.

You can check what does the var "products" contain with console.log(products) .This will display the content in the console (Firebug for example).

```
$('.checkOut').live('click',function(){
var products= new Array();
        $(".jshop_prod_cart").each(function(){
            var product = new Object();
        product.catid = $(this).find('[name="category_id"]').val();
        product.id = $(this).find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
        product.qanty = $(this).find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
        products.push(product) 


                         $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        data:products,
                        url: "/shop-portal/add?category_id="+product.catid+"&product_id="+product.id+"&quantity="+product.qanty,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        })
            })


});
```

Comment: Sorry V.V but if I use:
`url: "index.php/shop-portal/add?category_id="+category_id+"&product_id="+product_id+"&quantity="+quantity,`
 we get: `http://cardoso.co.za/index.php/index.php/shop-portal/add?category_id=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&product_id=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&quantity=[object%20HTMLInputElement]&undefined=undefined`

Comment: You must remove index.php from the URL. And I see that produc‌​t_id..., are HTML elements, not variables.