# Assigning a link to a button before click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685070/getting-details-from-one-dynamic-page-to-another-re-post) I asked for help with refining the output of a URL in a specific syntax, I have now managed to get this right, but only for one instance.

What I have researched is that I should use a cache in order to store these multiple URL values and then submit all of them when the time is right?

If you mouse over the "Buy" button on one of the many products, you will see the URL/link with the following syntax:

```
add?category_id=2&product_id=#
```

[image: Value parsed between product and checkout]

I have replicated this behaviour in [My Dynamic Cart System](http://cardoso.co.za) (outlined in red), however it will only push the URL at onclick. Is there a way to assign it to my submit button before Click?

The URL is created and called in this function:

```
$('.checkOut').live('click',function(){
    var products= new Array();
    $(".jshop_prod_cart").each(function(){
        var product = new Object();
        product.catid = $(this).find('[name="category_id"]').val();
        product.id = $(this).find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
        product.qanty = $(this).find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
        products.push(product);
        $.ajax({
            //type: 'POST',
            //data:products,
            //dataType: 'json',
            url: "shop-portal/add?category_id="+products[0].catid+"&product_id="+products[0].id+"&quantity="+products[0].qanty
        });
    });
});
```

Unless there is a way of forcing this into the URL address bar as it doesn't seem to get there at all, it just runs in the background ... (I think)

There are further "Controller" files which a lot of the content within this extension queries. How? I really don't know ... If anyone has tried to modify or customise the backend scripting of Joomshopping before, please help!

Answer (score 0):

you  could do it on page load, like:

```
var products= [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jshop_prod_cart").each(function(){
      var product = new Object();
      product.catid = $(this).find('[name="category_id"]').val();
      product.id = $(this).find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
      product.qanty = $(this).find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
      products.push(product);
    });
});
```

And on click

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkOut' ,function(){
  //your ajax code here
});
```

**Added**, you could use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in case your url's are loaded dynamically, like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkOut',function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Comment: The url is "created" from the products selected and thus will be in real-time, perhaps on a Focus event of sorts?

Comment: @user2265402 using Focus for such thing would not be good solution, you could use click event, and do like $(document).on('click', '.checkOut',function(){...}); in case your links are loaded dynamically..

Comment: I have tried it, tweaked it tested it and it doesn't seem to work, but thank you for your insight.